# how to write a custom function in User model in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4

I'm using laravel 5.4, in my User.php file I want to write a function like this :

```
public function isAdmin(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->user()->id == 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The function I want to use in my middleware and my blade file. How to write this ? 
Now it's giving me this error :

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\User::isAdmin() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given, called in
>   /home/mohib/MEGA/Projects/saifullah-website/app/Http/Middleware/isAdmin.php
>   on line 18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find out if the currently authenticated user is an Administrator, based on your logic, you could do something like this:

In `App\User.php`

```
public function isAdmin() 
{
    if ($this->id == 1) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and then, you can use it like this:

```
if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin())
{
    // do something here
}
```